# How do I clear dirt from an inventory slot?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to clear dirt from a particular inventory slot.

For example, I want dirt to be cleared only from the 6th slot and not from the other slots. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.hotbar 5 air
```

That will replace the 6th hotbar slot to be air. Unfortunately you cannot check if that slot specifically is dirt.